# Generate 2d plot on Matlab on given range

Tags: matlab

Im trying to plot the following on MATLAB not sure how to do it?

Y-axis ranges from -200 to 200
   X-axis ranges from 0 to 10

Now the function is

```
x = linspace (0,10,100);    
Yin = 10*sin (2*pi*x); 
Ym = Yin*4*cos(2*pi*x);
```

I'm trying to plot graph for (Yin, Ym) that will show me the range of 0 to 10 on X-axis and -200 to 200 and Y-axis

Comment: Edit your actual question. Don't make a comment.  Also your question is unclear.  Nowhere in your equations or formulations is there a dependent variable of `W`.

Comment: plot(V,Yin,V,Ym);
axis([min(V),max(V),min(W),max(W)]);

Comment: @PTRK Thanks a lot it worked. Basically, I had problem setting my variables using linspace and for loop but plotting part that's whats I was looking for. You are awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

For the plotting part the answer is:

```
plot(x,Yin,x,Ym);
axis([min(x),max(x),-200,200]);
```

But be careful with `Ym = Yin*4*cos(2*pi*x);` since `Yin` and `x` (thus `cos(2*pi*x)`) are vectors, `*` is the matrix multiplication. Since both `Yin` and `x` have the same shape, it may raise an error. Depending on what you want, you may need the elment-wise multiplication operator `.*` instead:  `Ym = 4*Yin.*cos(2*pi*x);`